# Find the most similar set of samples – A function that finds a cluster of a given size

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I need to find a cluster with a specific number of members. If I had distance data for any number of samples I want to find the first incidence in which three locations become clustered during agglomerative clustering. In otherwards, I want to find the most similar set of three samples.

`hclust(dist_object, method = complete)` provides me with clusters of size 3 via agglomeration  but it must be discerned visually through `plot(hclust(dist_object, method = complete))`.

I could create a function to use the `hclust()$merge` output to find the first occurrence during cluster agglomeration of a cluster with three members but am wondering if such a function already exists.

It is very possible that approaching this using clustering functions is not the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try approaching this problem from a different perspective.

For example, you could look for the distance to the second nearest neighbor, and choose that object where this distance is the smallest.

This will not necessarily give you the same result, but should be a lot faster.

Or you implement hierarchical clustering yourself (it's not very complicated) so you can stop early when the first cluster has the desired size.

Comment: Good suggestions. Second nearest neighbour is not precise enough for me, however working off those ideas: I could find the nearest neighbour to the centroid of each pair then choose the triplet with the smallest variance. This may become computationally cumbersome as the desired cluster size increases. Creating an hclust function could work too. Still hoping for a premade function though.